IPadOS 18 UiTabBarController 5+ tabs without ‘more’ button
Prior to iOS 18 apple allowed to have 6 tabs without ‘more’ button for iPads. Horizontal size class set to ‘compact’ reverts tab bar back to the bottom but only 5 tabs are allowed without more buttons. Any workaround for this?

I believe this answer will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78658285/6193411
From the answer above
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .unspecified
    }
}


Thanks. This was really hard to find in the linked array of answers! Appreciate you spelling this out.
